# Rudin PMA 8.4 summation indexing

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

In the following proof, I understand that we use 8.3 to swap the order of the summations, however why does the second sum turn into an infinite sum? Secondly, why do we now start from $n=m$ instead of n=0?

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n} \sum_{m=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
m
\end{array}\right) a^{n-m}(x-a)^{m} \\
=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left[\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
m
\end{array}\right) c_{n} a^{n-m}\right](x-a)^{m}
\end{array}
$$
[image]

[image]

Here is theorem 8.3 I referenced:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write the first summation for each $n$ you are summing over all $m$ from $0$ to $n$.

If now you want to sum over $m$ first, you notice that each $m$ will occurr in an $n$-sum only if $n$ is greater or equal to $m$, so that's why the second summation goes to infinity.

You can try representing this as a table

$$\begin{array}{c c c c c c}
n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &\dots\\ \hline
m & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0 & \dots\\
m &  & 1 & 1 & 1& 1 & 1 & \dots\\
m &  &  & 2 & 2& 2 & 2 & \dots\\
m &  &  &  & 3& 3 & 3 & \dots\\
m &  &  &  & & 4 & 4 & \dots\\
m &  &  &  & &  & 5 & \dots
\end{array}$$
in the first sum you are summing vertically over the indices, while in the second you are summing horizontally.

---

Here a second version of the table with the $(n,m)$ indices

$$\begin{array}{c c c c c c}
& n=0 & n=1 & n=2 & \color{red}{n=3} & n=4 & n=5 & \dots\\
m=0& (0,0) & (1,0) & (2,0) & (3,{\color{red}0}) & (4,0) & (5,0) &\dots\\
m=1 & & (1,1) & (2,1) & (3,{\color{red}1})& (4,1) & (5,1) & \dots\\
\color{blue}{m=2} & &  & ({\color{blue}2},2) & ({\color{blue}3},{\color{red}2})& ({\color{blue}4},2) & ({\color{blue}5},2) & \dots\\
m=3 & &  & & (3,{\color{red}3})& (4,3) & (5,3) & \dots\\
m=4 & &  & & & (4,4) & (5,4) & \dots\\
m=5 & &  & & & & (5,5) & \dots\\
\end{array}$$
in $\color{red}{red}$ the example when $n=3$ that we sum over $m$ from 0 to $3$. In $\color{blue}{blue}$ the example when $m=2$ that we sum over $n$ from 2 to $\infty$

Comment: Thanks I don't quite follow how the table works in the second case when we are summing horizontally. Does that mean I would sum $0+0+0+\dots$ + $1+1+1+\dots$? How can i read this properly?

Comment: No: it's a table of indices (in my edit I tried making it clearer but I admit it's not easy to explain

Comment: That is very clear! Now one more thing is unclear to me. Given we have a finite series and an infintie series, but theorem 8.3 is using two infinite series, how is it that we can apply the theorem to swap the order?

Comment: Well: a finite series always converges and is just a particular case of an infinite series finishing in $0$'s, so the theorem applies also in this case.